# The expectation value of an operator $X$ in the state $|α⟩$ is defined as $⟨α|X|α⟩$. What does this statement mean?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space

Can someone give me an intuitive understanding of what this statement means?

> The expectation value of an operator $X$ in the state $|α⟩$ is defined as $⟨α|X|α⟩$.

Not the algorithm or the taking average over ensemble part. Just purely what does this statement mean to convey. Here X is an Hermitian operator.

Comment: Do you know what *expected value* of a random variable mean (in probability theory)?

Comment: Yes, Please go ahead if you have some other intuition than the one mentioned below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you are measuring a system that behaves like a dice. This system has the states $|1\rangle,|2\rangle,\dots$ corresponding to "rolling" a 1 or 2 etc. We can construct the operator $X$ which measures the number that has been rolled. We construct $\hat X$ such that the states $|n\rangle$ are eigenstates and the numbers that are rolled are the eigenvalues corresponding to these states:
$$\hat X|n\rangle=n|n\rangle$$
For example $\hat X|3\rangle=3|3\rangle$. An important thing to note is that I define these states to be orthonormal: $\langle n|m\rangle=\delta_{m,n}$. That means that these states are 'definite states', which means that if you are 100% in that state, the probability of getting another state is zero.

Now we can consider the state $|\psi\rangle$ which is in a superposition of being in state 4 and 5 at the same time, being 90% in state 4 and 10% in state 5. This is written as follows:
$$|\psi\rangle=\sqrt{0.9}|4\rangle+\sqrt{0.1}|5\rangle$$
What is expected value of the dice?
\begin{align}
\langle\psi|\hat X|\psi\rangle&=\Big(\sqrt{0.9}\langle 4|+\sqrt{0.1}\langle5|\Big)\hat X\Big(\sqrt{0.9}|4\rangle+\sqrt{0.1}|5\rangle\Big)\\
&=\Big(\sqrt{0.9}\langle 4|+\sqrt{0.1}\langle5|\Big)\Big(4\sqrt{0.9}|4\rangle+5\sqrt{0.1}|5\rangle\Big)\\
&=0.9\cdot4+0.1\cdot5
\end{align}
Like we expect, it is 90% 4 and 10% 5

---

As a final note, usually we don't construct operators to have certain eigenstates and eigenvalues but we do it the other way around. We have an operator and we find out what its eigenstates and eigenvalues are. Note that when an operator is Hermitian, its eigenvalues will be real and its eigenvectors will form an orthonormal basis.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement,

> Not the algorithm or the taking average over ensemble part. Just
> purely what does this statement mean to convey. Here X is an Hermitian
> operator.

seems to contain the answer.

Perhaps a better word than *expectation* is *average* as when you throw a dice with an average value of $3.5$ and you would not expect to get that value.

So there is a physical quantity $x$ which is associated with and operator $X$ eg total energy and the Hamiltonian.

The physical quantity can take certain values - eigenvalues, $a_1,\,a_2,\,a_3\,\ldots,$ of operator $X$.

The prob­a­bil­i­ties of get­ting those val­ues are ac­cord­ing to quan­tum me­chan­ics the square mag­ni­tudes of the co­ef­fi­cients when the wave func­tion is writ­ten in terms of the eigen­func­tions of $X$.

In other words, if $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$, $\alpha_3 \ldots$, are the eigen­func­tions of op­er­a­tor $X$, and the wave func­tion is
$\Psi = c_1 \alpha_1 + c_2 \alpha_2 + c_3 \alpha_3 + \ldots $ then $| c_1|^2$ is the prob­a­bil­ity of value $a_1$, $| c_2|^2$ the prob­a­bil­ity of value $a_2,\dots$

The expectation value is $| c_1|^2 a_1 + |c_2|^2 a_2 + |c_3|^2 a_3 + \ldots$ just like for dice when the average value is $\frac 16 \cdot 1+\frac 16\cdot 2+\frac 16\cdot 3+ \frac 16 \cdot 4+ \frac 16 \cdot 5+ \frac 16\cdot 6$.